# Ajax запрос возвращает 0 как исправить Плагин WP

Tags: ajax, wordpress

сама функция

```
function getdata() {  
$('#temp').on('click', function() {
        var result = {};
        $('.hexagon-cards-drop').each(function() {
            var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
            var elements = [];  
            elements.push('<?php single_cat_title() ?>');
            var image = $('.img1 img').attr('src');

            $(this).find('.wrap').each(function() {
                var textarea = $(this).find("#my_textarea");
                var image_find = $(this).find('img');
                var text_write = '';
                    if(textarea.length){
                        text_write = textarea.val();
                        elements.push(text_write);
                    }else{
                        text_val = $(this).text();
                        elements.push(text_val);
                    }
                    if (image_find){
                        var image=image_find.attr('src');
                        elements.push(image);
                    }
            });
            result[type] = elements
        });
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(myJsonString);
        $.ajax({

            url: '<?php echo admin_url("../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php") ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'save_data',
                data: myJsonString,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                $('#temp').text('Otpravka na server');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#temp').text('Send');
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
}

getdata();
```

в этом же файле внизу.

```
function save_data() {
    $array_jsons = mb_convert_encoding((json_encode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, true )),'UTF-8');
    $cur_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    var_dump($cur_user_id);
    add_user_meta( $cur_user_id, 'json', $array_jsons );
}

public function register_actions() {
    add_action('wp_ajax_save_data', 'save_data'); // wp_ajax_{ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПАРАМЕТРА ACTION!!}
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_data', 'save_data');  // wp_ajax_nopriv_{ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ACTION!!}
}
```

И в отдельном файле где подключаются хуки

```
private function define_public_hooks() {

$plugin_public = new Drag_Drop_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_styles' );
$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_scripts' );

//$this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'register_shortcodes' );

//$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_footer', $plugin_public, 'add_text_footer' );



$this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'register_shortcodes' );


$this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'register_actions' );



}
```

AJAX при нажатии на сохранить всегда выводит 0 в консоль , почему так ?

Answer (score 0):

Для избежания вывода лишней информации функция, обрабатывающая ajax-запрос (в вашем случае это `save_data()`), должна завершаться выходом с ипользованием `die();` или `wp_die();`

т. е.

```
function save_data(){

//...

wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Поэтому и получается , что нечего не сохраняет и не работает  ?

Answer (score 0):

Я использую вот такой вариант завершения каждого ajax-коллбэка

```
    function save_data() 
{    
$answer = ['code' => 200, 'message' => 'Ok', 'data' => json_encode( $res )];

echo json_encode($answer);
wp_die();
}
```

И дальше в js-части парсинг этого респонса.